# determining the blowup of $Y^2=X^3+X^2$ at the origin

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $C = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{A}^2_k : y^2 = x^3+x^2\}$ as an affine variety over some algebraically closed field $k$. From the real picture we see that this curve is self-intersecting at the origin. I want to show this by blowing up $C$ and determining its fiber at the origin.

Formally, let $C'$ be the closure of $\{ (p,l) \in C \times \mathbb{P}^1 : 0 \neq p \in l \}$ in $\mathbb{A}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^1$, and $\pi : C' \to C$ the canonical projection. I want to show that $\pi^{-1}(\mathbf{0}) = \{(\mathbf{0},(1:1)),(\mathbf{0},(1:-1))\}$.

By covering $C'$ by two affine open subspaces, I was able to show that this fiber consists of at most these two points: Consider for example the affine open subspace $U_0 = \{ ((x,y),(s:t)) \in C' : s \neq 0\}$. It is easy to show that $U_0$ is contained in the common zero set of $Y^2-X^3-X^2$ and $(\frac T S)^2 -X -1$, so the points $(\mathbf{0},(s:t)) \in U_0$ satisfy $s = \pm t$.

But now I have difficulties to show the converse. Why do the points $(\mathbf{0},(1:1))$ and $(\mathbf{0},(1:-1))$ belong to $C'$?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest argument is just to show that $C$, together with those two points, is closed and irreducible.

Look at the closed subvariety $V$ of $\mathbb{A}^2\times\mathbb{P}^1$ defined by $y^2=x^3+x^2$ and $uy=vx$.  The point is to show that it has two irreducible components: the $\mathbb{P}^1$ lying over the origin, and $C'$.

Take $u\neq 0$; set $u=1$ for simplicity.  Then we have $v^2 x^2 = x^3 +x^2$, so we see that there are two components, cut out by $x=0$ and $v^2 = x+1$ respectively.  Both points we want already lie in the second curve, so we're done—though in general we should check $v\neq 0$ as well if we think there might be more points there.

Comment: Dear Slade, your answer is a bit confusing because the two points of $C'$ above $(0,0)\in C$  **do** satisfy $v\neq0$ : indeed they are given by $x=y=0 ; u=1, v=\pm 1$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I wasn't quite sure how to word it.  The point is that $V$ is covered by the opens $\{u\neq 0\}$ and $\{v\neq 0\}$, and if we're trying to determine the fiber over $(0,0)$, then in principle we need to look at both of these sets.  Here, there are two points and they both lie in both sets, but Dune also has already concluded that there can't be more than two.  So we can check either one and stop there.

Comment: Dear Slade: yes, I agree that  it is a bit awkward to write a precise and complete proof.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Slade! Actually that $C \setminus \{0\}$ together with those two points is closed already follows by my approach since this set ($C''$ say) is locally given as the common zero set of regular maps. For example $D(S) \cap C'' = V(Y^2-X^3-X^2, \frac{T^2}{S^2}-X-1)$. But even then it is not a priori clear that $C' = C''$. Why couldn't $C \setminus \{0\}$ be already closed in $\mathbb{A}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^1$? Or $(C \setminus \{0\}) \cup \{(\mathbf{0},(1:1))\}$?

Comment: @Dune To be safe, I've changed "closed" to "closed and irreducible".  If $C'\setminus\{p\}$ were closed for some $p$, then $C' = (C'\setminus\{p\})\cup \{p\}$ gives a nontrivial decomposition.  If it's not clear why $C'$ is irreducible, note that I basically demonstrated an isomorphism between $C'\cap \{u\neq 0\}$ and the curve $v^2 = x+1$ in $\mathbb{A}_2$.

Comment: Ah I see, showing irreducibility is the trick! Thank you very much!